Proxmox Docker OPNSense Firewall issue
I'm currently configuring my root server and I'm hitting a roadblock. My current setup looks like the following:

Root Hetzner server with Proxmox
OPNSense VM for handling all incomming traffic besides SSH and 8006 for Proxmox
MailCow VM (OPNSense nat for all the required Mail Ports)
Docker VM for other containers containing a Caddy reverse proxy for ssl handling

This handles the redirection to the web services of the mailcow VM



Now I try to install roundcube on the docker host and have it connect to the mailcow vm. But I only get
errors: <e30816ed> IMAP Error: Login failed for e@mail.com against mail.host.name from 10.0.10.10 (X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4). Could not connect to mail.host.name:143: Connection refused in /var/www/html/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 211 (POST /?_task=login&_action=login)

The connection from the mailcow VM to the docker vm via IP works just fine. A netcat connection to the mailcow vm on port 143 is also working but using the mail.host.name results in a connection refused.
How do I configure OPNSense to allow for connections to mail.host.name from within my network or is there an alternative to perform some local dns resolution.
If I change the roundcube config to use the ip, the connection works but gets aborted because the ssl certificate does not match the hostname.
Thans for you help!

What you're looking for is split horizon DNS probably.
The simplest (non-scaling) way to solve this is to add mail.host.name to /etc/hosts, as it by default takes precedence over DNS for name resolution. That doesn't scale very well however.

That was it, i used this guide on cofiguring split dns for opnsense if anyone has the same problem: https://homenetworkguy.com/how-to/configure-split-dns-opnsense-using-unbound/
